# start standalone zookeeper server in java

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am not able to figure out how to start zookeeper standalone server in java ? I know how to start the server with command line. I looked into the documentation of zookeeper but couldn't able to find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to read that somebody is trying to implement a highly reliable application using Apache Zookeeper.

If you've worked with Sockets (Java networking) before, you shouldn't have problems. If in any case, you can find many samples on Internet. A very basic one I can provide you as an example is this one:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

If you already known Java Networking programming, there should not be any problems to you to adapt server and client to a Zookeeper environment. It is like adding "a plugin".

I implemented an application based on zookeeper sometime ago, it is better when you "wrap" zookeeper, many known Web Systems  (such Netflix) uses this framework but they "wrap" it instead of using it pure. Anyway, when zookeeper appeared as a requirement, this tutorial helped me a lot:

http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2012/01/apache-zookeeper-maven-example.html

All the information and bases you need to know about zookeeper, for sure, you know, can find it in the Web Page:

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/

I also obtained many useful information from that documentation. For sure, the application I implemented almost a year ago is running perfectly and it is very fast and reliable.

There are many examples on the web, many tutorials, even when REST Service providers. But for me, these work the best and were very useful during the time I was implementing that zookeeper based application.

Hope, somehow, I was able to help you.

Best regards and happy coding.